# How can I position the object origin precisely on a specific axis?

Tags: origin

I'm a newbie and again, I'm here with my stupid question as usual.

[image]

As you can see here I try to make a door right, and I trying to move the origin point of this door into the middle of the bottom of it. I successfully snap it to the X and Z axis by following some random Youtube video. But my problem is I don't know how to make it into the middle of the Y-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can directly move the origin point by checking *Origins* in the *Tool tab > Transform*.
To snap it precisely to axis, enable *Absolute Grid Snap*.

*Example of moving origin point with and without snapping*

[image]

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh !!!!!!!! Thank you so much !!!