# Change origin point in edit mode without 3d cursor

Tags: origin

Is there a way to change origin point in edit mode without moving 3d cursor? If I remember correctly, there was a short cut in edit mode to move around the origin point. Does anyone know?

Comment: maybe this video will anwser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wbvsh4kXKTI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I position the object origin precisely on a specific axis?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173891/how-can-i-position-the-object-origin-precisely-on-a-specific-axis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the shortcut but I do know how to do it without one.

In the top right corner, check *Origins* and with the move tool you can freely move your origin. When you are done check the Origins button again and you can move stuff around normally again.

[image: Top right corner]

Comment: Thanks Manex! I guess I remembered wrong. I do it in object mode either by clicking origins check box as you mentioned or use short cut ctrl+.(period)