# Cannot shake off origin point when accessing new object

Tags: objects, origin

I thought, as a Noob, I was getting the hang of this but then something simple confounds me.

At some point, when adding a new object (either plane or cube), any action, such as Move or rotate, seems stuck on the origin point and just affects that. I cannot find a way to free this up. I know it will be something simple but I cannot find mention of such an issue in other questions. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps you checked origin transforms by mistake? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173897/

Comment: Thanks you were right although I have no idea how I did that and indeed it took me ages to find it in the Tool tab for the object to uncheck it. I searched everywhere else. All is ok now. Thanks

Comment: Should have clicked on your link...